# UART noise on A6 GSM module

Tags: noise, uart, gprs

I'm using the A6 GSM module to send data from my sensors board to a server via GPRS.

The problem is that most of times, usually when the module attaches to the network or connects to the server, noise appears on the UART A6 TX line and the controller reads garbage. After this noise appears, the next command sent to the module gets a CME error response. I suspect the noise it generated by the chip, maybe caused by the RF transmitter.

Sometines it works, but most of the times it fails. I've tried putting 100pF capacitors to GND on the UART lines and lowering the baud rate to 2400 baud, but with the same results.

If it has anything to do with this problem, I mention that I am applying 3.3V level on the UART line (the A6 supports 2.8V), since I did not have a voltage translator available when I made the board.

**Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a solution or should I use a different GSM module?**

**UPDATE**

The GSM module is a ready made breakout board from [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/A6-GPRS-GSM-Module-Adapter-Board-Plate-Quad-band-850-900-1800-1900MHZ-Antenna/322121300920?epid=560909942&hash=item4affecfbb8:g:rXEAAOSwFe5Xzo-D). The module is connected to my microcontroller board by wires. My power supply is a R-78E5.0-1.0 DC-DC converter that provides 5V/1A. I've tried powering the module from a separate 2.5A power supply, but the results are the same. These are my schematic and setup.

[image: Schematic and setup]

The SIM card is connected via an extender. I've also tried without the extender, but with the same results. In the setup you can also see the logic analyzer connected to the UART lines and GND.

This is the output from the logic analyzer (the last waveform is module TX analogic):

[image: Logic analyzer captures]

The noise consists of bursts of impulses, from 2.2V to 3.7V, or longer pulses from 1.9V to 3V. I usually receive CME Error 50 (EXE_FAIL) and CME Error 58 (which is not described in the module documentation).

I tried connecting the antenna via an RG316 cable coax cable and the **noise disappeared**. With or without shielded wires to the microcontroller board, there was no noise. **Does anybody know why?**

[image: Antenna connected by cable]

Comment: (a) Do you have access to (and experience using) an oscilloscope? (b) Is this a ready-made A6 GSM module, or your own? It would help if you to edit your question and add a link to the web page for your specific module (if it's ready-made), and also add an in-focus, appropriately-cropped photo of your specific hardware setup. A schematic diagram of the module will also help, especially if it's your own design. (c) How have you confirmed that your power supply reaching the GSM module is adequate? (d) Getting the specific CME error code number may also be helpful. Do you have that?

Comment: I suspect it is a common mode RF noise problem that can be solved with a CM choke and shunt caps to earth ground. or simply STP UART cables with earth ground.

Comment: @SamGibson Please read the updated question.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I will try with STP cable. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Near E field coupling of RF to wire mesh without ground plane for antenna to isolate logic is a good way to induce interference since it radiates radially from antenna.

Comment: Ideally antenna should sit on top of a ground plane both above logic below in a location to broadcast line of site without reflections other than ground plane with antenna connector in centre. Ground wires can pick up RF from inductance

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Can you please provide a detailed answer so I can properly understand why it works with cable and why it doesn't without cable? And describe what measures I have to take to eliminate the noise.

Comment: How long was coax cable?  Did you try placing antenna near serial cable then point towards near it Then how far away is everything else? What package design did you wish?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist The cable is 10cm long. I've placed the antenna both near the GSM module (almost in the same place as it would have been when connected to the onboard SMA) and far from it, and the noise was not present (I've tried shorter cable and the results were the same). Everything was in the positions shown in the image. I did not understand the last question.

Comment: It’s hard to convert photo of the GSM into E fields but it appears you have solved a design issue with their ground layout by accident.